# Как задать событие метки с собственным шаблоном? yandex map 2.1

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.7, 37.6],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });
  var myPlacemarkCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

  var polygonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="search-map-marker">555</div>');

  var polygonPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [55.662693, 37.558416], {}, {
      iconLayout: polygonLayout
    }
  );
  map.geoObjects.add(polygonPlacemark);
  polygonPlacemark.events
    .add('mouseenter', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseenter');
      e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#greenIcon');
    })
    .add('mouseleave', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseleave');
      e.get('target').options.unset('preset');
    });

  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(map.getCenter());
  map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myPlacemark.events
    .add('mouseenter', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseenter');
      e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#greenIcon');
    })
    .add('mouseleave', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseleave');
      e.get('target').options.unset('preset');
    });
});
```

```css
</style> <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=package.full&mode=debug" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <style> html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.placemark_layout_container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* Квадратный макет метки */

.square_layout {
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  top: -23px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid #218703;
  background-color: #F8FDF7;
  color: #218703;
}
/* Круглый макет метки */

.circle_layout {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  top: -23px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid #225D9C;
  color: #225D9C;
  line-height: 46px;
  /* Это CSS свойство не будет работать в Internet Explorer 8 */
  border-radius: 50px;
}
/* Макет метки с "хвостиком" */

.polygon_layout {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid #943A43;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -28px;
  top: -76px;
  color: #943A43;
}
.polygon_layout:after,
.polygon_layout:before {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.polygon_layout:after {
  border-top-color: #943A43;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.polygon_layout:before {
  border-top-color: #943A43;
  border-width: 16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
.search-map-marker {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 49px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #53b50a;
  border-color: #326d06;
}
.search-map-marker:before {
  background-color: #53b50a;
  border-color: #326d06;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 0;
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 24px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Как повесить событие на зеленую метку?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Немного не дочитали вы документацию, см. последний раздел [Интерактивность геообъектов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts-docpage/). Для нестандартных точек необходимо описывать их геометрию, "активные области".

Ну и рабочий [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv6ynx4t/3/).

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.7, 37.6],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });
  var myPlacemarkCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

  var polygonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="search-map-marker">555</div>');

  var polygonPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [55.662693, 37.558416], {}, {
      iconLayout: polygonLayout,
      iconShape: {
        type: 'Rectangle',
        // Прямоугольник описывается в виде двух
        // точек - верхней левой и нижней правой.
        coordinates: [
          [-25, -25],
          [25, 25]
        ]
      }
    }
  );
  map.geoObjects.add(polygonPlacemark);
  polygonPlacemark.events
    .add('mouseenter', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseenter');
      e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#greenIcon');
    })
    .add('mouseleave', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseleave');
      e.get('target').options.unset('preset');
    });

  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(map.getCenter());
  map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myPlacemark.events
    .add('mouseenter', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseenter');
      e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#greenIcon');
    })
    .add('mouseleave', function(e) {
      console.log('mouseleave');
      e.get('target').options.unset('preset');
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.placemark_layout_container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Квадратный макет метки */
.square_layout {
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  top: -23px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid #218703;
  background-color: #F8FDF7;
  color: #218703;
}

/* Круглый макет метки */
.circle_layout {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -23px;
  top: -23px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border: 2px solid #225D9C;
  color: #225D9C;
  line-height: 46px; /* Это CSS свойство не будет работать в Internet Explorer 8 */
  border-radius: 50px;
}

/* Макет метки с "хвостиком" */
.polygon_layout {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 4px solid #943A43;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -28px;
  top: -76px;
  color: #943A43;
}

.polygon_layout:after,
.polygon_layout:before {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.polygon_layout:after {
  border-top-color: #943A43;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.polygon_layout:before {
  border-top-color: #943A43;
  border-width: 16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
}

.search-map-marker {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 49px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #53b50a;
  border-color: #326d06;
}

.search-map-marker:before {
  background-color: #53b50a;
  border-color: #326d06;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 0;
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: 24px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&load=package.full&mode=debug" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь.